# Constructor in java

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have created an object of a class with no parameters, but at some point in the program I want to pass parameters to it's constructor.

What do I have to do?

My class has 3 levels or inheritance so in the constructor I use 'super()' to pass value to the base class.

```
public void main(String args[])
{
     Obj obj1 = new Obj();

     // Some more code
     // After the code i want to pass value to constructor of Obj class
     // So the Constructor of obj class will pass value to the upperclass(parent class)

     /* What should I write here? */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear as to where you're going with this.  Once you instantiate the object, **the constructor has been called**, so attempting to reinvoke it makes no sense.

Comment: You don't. The constructor is used to construct a new object, not to modify existing ones.

Comment: I don't understand this either.  If the ctor needs a parameter that is not available till later, construct the object later.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering and sorry for unclear question this is my first time asking online... Thank you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a constructor after the fact. An instance is only constructed *once*.

You will need to find another method (literally) to pass whatever you want to your instance. Maybe just write a new method that takes the same parameters as your constructor?

Comment: but then if i create a method in the class.... how can I invoke an upper class constructor

Comment: @AsiBaka You cannot. Construction is only *once*. If you cannot set that value in your base/super class after construction, then what you want is not possible. Most likely for a good reason.